# Rewrite url without id in htaccess

Tags: url-rewriting

I would like redirect a page without using id.
I would redirect from this link:

mywebsite.com/blog/mycategory/

to

mywebsite.com/blog/category/index.php?name=mycategory

I try this in htaccess but not work:

RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$   blog/categoria/index.php?name=$2 [L]

Answer (score 0):

the error was $2 must be $1 the first parameters in ()

this is correct:

RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$   blog/categoria/index.php?name=$1 [L]